# How to handle if we are using two different urls in one cypress test

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress

I have a requirement where I need to visit the first URL(ex-www.example.com) and do some AWS operations like verifying the file in AWS S3. After completing all the operations, it should go to the second URL(ex-www.example1.com) in the same test. Need a solution for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run them separately for this to work.

```
  it("Test", function () {
    cy.visit('ex-www.example.com');
    aws operations here

  });

  it("Test", function () {
    cy.visit('ex-www.example1.com');
  });
```

If you try this:

```
  it("Full Happy Test", function () {
    cy.visit('ex-www.example.com');
    aws operations here
    cy.visit('ex-www.example1.com');

  });
```

You will get this error:

```
"cy.visit() failed because you are attempting to visit a URL that is of a 
different origin."
```